# How to make my websites content available as Tor .onion and Clearnet .com?

Tags: nginx

I'm running a website with Nginx which I would like to be accessible by Tor and by Clearnet. Currently it's only reachable by Clearnet, e.g. `www.example.com`.

Of course people just can go to `www.example.com` through Tor browser, but I want to have a `.onion` address too for the same website.

I want the website and content to be accessible by `www.example.com/` and `xyzsfexample.onion/`. So they see content from `/var/www/www.example.com/web/index.php` as `xyzsfexample.onion/index.php`; IF they browse on `xyzsfexample.onion`; IF they browse on `example.com` they should see `example.com/index.php`.

How do I set this up and how must Nginx be configured to do both?

Comment: Nginx won't care if the site is served in the clear or over the TOR network. You  can set up `server` blocks ('virtual servers') for your different domains, which I suspect is necessary, though perhaps not. Either way, you can have both domains served from the same directory to reduce content duplication, it's just a matter of figuring out how to serve a TOR website at all. I suspect you may get better answers in the Server Fault SE site (I flagged the question for a moderator to consider migration).

Comment: Have you considered using a ServerBlock in Nginx to define a website and then using Tor's guide to hidden services to setup the onion address (https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en)?

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com xyzsfexample.onion;

    root /var/www/www.example.com/web/;
    index index.php;

    [...]
}
```